# Windows WritePrivateProfileString returning ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: winapi

I have a program saving settings to an INI file. A few days ago, it saved all of the sections and items correctly. Today it started reporting "*Access is denied*" for all items in all sections, except for the 2nd and 9th (out of 9 total) sections -- those two it still writes perfectly.

I've tried disabling all of my anti-virus software but that had no effect.  And it was enable last week when the program was still saving the whole file.

I would normally expect something I changed, except this is a DLL that has not changed this month, so I see this as unlikely.  I found the errors using the Visual Studio debugger's trace points without modifying any code.  I also had it log all of the parameters being passed to `WritePrivateProfileString()` and they are correct, at least as the debugger sees and logs them.

So... can anyone provide any ideas on what could possibly have triggered this behavior?  The only consistent part is that the same section/item pairs fail every time, but SOME of them WORK every time -- all to the same file, called from the same function in the DLL.

I'm at a total loss on how to proceed from here and praying for some insight.  (hopeful smile)

**EDIT**

I've seen other questions like this with suggestions to use a 3rd party INI file library. I have not been able to find one with all the functionality of the WINAPI Profile functions (and I use it all!) -- does such a thing exist? I have several hundred INI files, averaging over a hundred lines each, used (and sometimes *shared*) by a collection of over 50 applications, so I **really** don't want to change the way settings are loaded & saved.

**David Hefferman**: Let's just say I don't care about Microsoft's plan to make configuration settings almost impossible for typical users to manipulate. My INI files are filled with comments that explain the settings as well... not even an option in the registry.  How about portability?  Change an INI on one machine and when it is correct, copy it to all the others, done.  Registry?  Yeah, right.

**Internal Server Error**  Nope.  The sections in question have only a few items and contain less than 256 BYTES total in the entire section.

**YangXiaoPo-MSFT**  Just BEFORE the explanation of the search path, the documentation states that when a path is included (and I ALWAYS include a full path!) none of that searching is performed and the file is opened (or created) in the given location.

**Jabberwocky**  FWIW, the ini file name being used is `"C:\RMCS\simLoop2\simComm.ini"`.  I have tested on a second machine (a "clean" Windows 11 system) and I get the same problem.

Comment: The documentation says: "Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Applications should store initialization information in the registry." You should have stopped calling this function over 25 years ago.

Comment: I agree with David here, FWIW, but I also seem to recall there were certain size limitations with sections in .ini files - could that be what's biting you here?

Comment: [WritePrivateProfileString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-writeprivateprofilestringa#remarks) searches the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping` as priority and finally *look for the actual initialization file on the disk and read its contents*. Also check the access right of your initialization file.

Comment: You should show the .ini file and its exact path. Not sure if this helps answering the question, but every bit of information may be useful. Also, did you test this on another computer under similar conditions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think Registry is also obsolete method. About INI files - `WriteProfileString` may be for compatibility (writing in WIN.INI) but `WritePrivateProfileString` is something different and I don't thing it is worse than Registry. Of course INI file location must be outside Windows directory (`C:\WINDOWS`).

Comment: @i486 no, it's not in Program Files (from the question content) and confirmed in an edit.

Comment: @Jabberwocky However access rights to file are not known. It looks that root directory is from "Remote Management Center System" or other old software. If it is installed with admin rights...

Comment: @i486 Registry is certainly not obsolete. If it was then there'd be similar text in MSDN. There isn't. INI files are find for configuration, but it's really not ideal to use these API functions to work with INI files. There are far better ways to work with INI files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan IMHO, new software are not using Registry or have limited use. XML or other configuration files are the new way (I hope you will agree at least partially). Copying settings from config file is easier and more convenient than export/import of Registry keys.

Comment: @i486 config files are good. My point is that these functions shouldn't be used. I never said to use registry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why not use `WritePrivateProfileString`? You think they can be removed from Win32 in future version? This is impossible. On the other hand INI format is simple, flexible and convenient. I use it sometimes, especially in Unicode (16-bit chars) version. `.conf` files in Linux world are very similar and used without plans for abandonment (at least in near future).

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense to use Windows API for a INI file parsing and writing. I'd use library code for that.

Comment: This issue is really strange, I'm curious what the problem is. Maybe you should try to make a [mcve]. That being said, I'd also rather use some library (https://github.com/pulzed/mINI looks pretty cool) to manage your ini files. I've used WritePrivateProfileString long time ago I recall that I encountered some frustrating limitations, I can't remember which ones though.

Comment: @486 I don't think that the access rights are changing between the first, the second and the third calls to `WritePrivateProfileString` and only the second call is failing with access denied.  As for other config file types, neither XML nor JSON (the two that I see most often these days) are for anyone except experienced coders. INI (and linux config) files are usually easy enough for John Q. Public to edit.  Plus, calls to the ainapi profile functions are scattered throughout over a million lines of source in over 50 projects.  Not. Gonna. Change.  Sorry

Comment: I looked at minini as well as several other options on github and (a) they all require a redesign of all of our code and (b) the few that support writing say they recreate the complete file and write everything from a memory-cached copy of the sections, items and values:  This would destroy all comments and lose temporarily commented settings.  That is unacceptable, so those are unusable.

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information in consideration of that you get the same problem on a second machine (a "clean" Windows 11 system)?